# Just booted up my Lenovo laptop and certain keys on the keyboard are not working correctly

Tags: keyboard, keys

Laptop: Lenovo IdeaPad 2 17ITL6

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3

<kbd>s</kbd> - brings up selection
<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> - prints ~
<kbd>i</kbd> - prints ^[[2~

several other keys show nothing.

There may have been some auto updates that ran recently.
Tried running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

It is set to Generic 105-key PC (there are no Lenovo configs to pick from)

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem to me